# android default calendar database schema

Tags: android, database, calendar, schema

somebody please tell me what is the primary key used in the android's default calendar database when we add new events. Is somebody know the database schema of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old thread... but for others looking for similar kind of answer see
"[Looking for new Calendar database schema in Froyo](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=688095)"

Comment: Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I saw there are n number of posts on StackOverflow which provides links as answer. Does it violates some rules???

Comment: There was a time when they were OK, but also, sometimes moderators just don't see them yet. :) [See the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) part where it says that answers which are 'barely more than a link' will be deleted.